# Launch a macOS app when a specific bluetooth device connects?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, macos-mojave

Anyone know if there's an app or script which could do this? I want a specific macOS app to open when a recognised bluetooth devices connects. I've had a look but can't seem to see anything, i'd have thought it would be possible though.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it or ask for it to be migrated - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358929/macos-open-app-when-specific-bluetooth-device-connects

Comment: You can set up a [Launch Agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` to watch the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` file for changes. Each time a Bluetooth device is connected/disconnected the plist file is modified. You can write a script that reads the file for the target device and act accordingly.

Comment: There is also an app called [EventsScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html), which among other things has the ability to do that which you're asking. Note that I and not affiliated with the developer of EventsScripts, Mousedown Software, but I do use the product.